# Blazor client-side Application level exception handling

Tags: exception, blazor, blazor-client-side

How to globally handle application level exceptions for client-side Blazor apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a singleton service that handles the WriteLine event. This will be fired only on errors thanks to `Console.SetError(this);`

```
public class ExceptionNotificationService : TextWriter
{
    private TextWriter _decorated;
    public override Encoding Encoding => Encoding.UTF8;

    public event EventHandler<string> OnException;

    public ExceptionNotificationService()
    {
        _decorated = Console.Error;
        Console.SetError(this);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        OnException?.Invoke(this, value);

        _decorated.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

You then add it to the Startup.cs file in the ConfigureServices function:

```
services.AddSingleton<ExceptionNotificationService>();
```

To use it you just subscribe to the OnException event in your main view.

[Source](https://remibou.github.io/Exception-handling-in-Blazor/)

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work unfortunately. What kinds of exceptions is this suppose to catch?

Comment: This catches everything that would normally throw an error in the browser console. The way it's setup, those errors still show in the console, but you can act on them or log them if necessary. Which part isn't working exactly? Have you made sure to subscribe to the OnException event somewhere in your code?
You can maybe put some console.writelines in there to see if anything is being caught at all.

Comment: @Gerrit Please include where you "subscribe to the OnException event somewhere in your code" for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

@Gerrit's answer is not up to date. Now you should use ILogger for handling unhandled exception.

My example

```
public interface IUnhandledExceptionSender
{
    event EventHandler<Exception> UnhandledExceptionThrown;
}

public class UnhandledExceptionSender : ILogger, IUnhandledExceptionSender
{

    public event EventHandler<Exception> UnhandledExceptionThrown;

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state,
        Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {            
        if (exception != null)
        {                
            UnhandledExceptionThrown?.Invoke(this, exception);
        }            
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
var unhandledExceptionSender = new UnhandledExceptionSender();
var myLoggerProvider = new MyLoggerProvider(unhandledExceptionSender);
builder.Logging.AddProvider(myLoggerProvider);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUnhandledExceptionSender>(unhandledExceptionSender);
```

Comment: I want to try this method after another I'm working on. Does it work in 2023?

Comment: @TheLegendaryCopyCoder, sorry, but I don't know. I haven't touched Blazor for a couple years

Comment: Just an update. This works. Its not perfect, sometimes it doesn't catch non awaited async methods failing. Hopefully the new exception handling in Blazor 8 can provide a better solution.