# Console.SetError(myTextWriter) does nothing

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side

I try to find a way to handle unhandled exception. I've found next [Blazor client-side Application level exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267387/blazor-client-side-application-level-exception-handling).

```
services.AddSingleton<ExceptionNotificationService>();
...
public class ExceptionNotificationService : TextWriter
{
    private TextWriter _decorated;
    public override Encoding Encoding => Encoding.UTF8;

    public event EventHandler<string> OnException;

    public ExceptionNotificationService()
    {
        _decorated = Console.Error;
        Console.SetError(this);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        OnException?.Invoke(this, value);

        _decorated.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

I check this code, it doesn't change anything. Exceptions are writing into Browser Console, method `WriteLine(string value)` is not executing at all. I'm sure that `Console.SetError(this)` has been executed. Why does it do nothing?

Because of I has no idea how realize a reason, I started to try next uncanny things

1. change `Console.SetError(this)` to `Console.SetOut(this)`.

It do changes. I get 1000 errors in Browser Console and application not started.

2. change `_decorated = Console.Error` to `_decorated = Console.Out`
   I get 1000 infos in Browser Console and application not started again.

It's a pity, I can't make any conclusions, except that `Console.SetError` is broken in WebAssembly and `Console.SetOut` is ok.

Comment: First, are you sure the source outputs to the error stream ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I purposelly add to the some places code throwing exceptions. Browser Console shows me them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I check this code, it doesn't change anything

In the version you posted, errors are forwarde with `_decorated.WriteLine(value);` so 'no change' is the expected outcome.
However, when you remove that line they still show up, that is odd. I just tested with v3.2.

> except that Console.SetError is broken

No, it isn't. You can test it like

```
 Console.Error.WriteLine($"Current count {currentCount}");
```

that passes through your overridden WriteLine just fine.

But [according to GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/36c6c2c2a6af84659cf03be4265d82103682a062/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly/src/Rendering/WebAssemblyRenderer.cs#L118) the errors are now written to the Logger, not (directly) to the Console. That is a change since that other answer was posted. You probably see  `crit:` before your errors, that is the LogLevel.

Now I don't directly know how to reconfigure the logging, that might be another question to ask here.

Comment: "no changes' I meant "method WriteLine(string value) is not executing at all" and no other changes exist. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: I've figured out how to reconfigure the logging https://stackoverflow.com/a/62869156/5574962